# serialization in server/client

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

There is server and client. Client connects to the server and sends to it an object. That object must be returned back to the client.

Server:

```
     ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
     ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        while (true){   
                    msg = (Message)inStream.readObject();
                    .........
                     outStream.writeObject(msg);
                     outStream.flush();
```

When I write like this I get **java.net.SocketException: socket closed**  at *msg = (Message)inStream.readObject();*

When I'm trying to put it into the cycle like this:

```
        while (true){   
                    ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
                    ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
                    msg = (Message)inStream.readObject();
                    .........
                     outStream.writeObject(msg);
                     outStream.flush();
```

I get **java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed** at *ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());*

Client:

```
 addr = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        socket = new Socket(addr, PORT);
        ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outStream.writeObject(new Message(this.name,"/**//**/"));
        outStream.flush();
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Message answer = (Message)inStream.readObject();
```

Tell me what am I doing wrong?
Are there any others ways to make the server wait some data from the client?
Btw sorry for my English, It isn't my native language.

Comment: Maybe the client was closed, before the server was able to write. Once the application has terminated the vm release all of its resources/closes its socket.

Comment: How are you getting your `Socket`? Is there a `ServerSocket` involved? Because there should be and we'd love to see that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You* are closing the socket. Closing either the input stream or the output stream of a `Socket` closes the other stream and the socket.

Possibly you are allocating multiple streams. The `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` should be constructed, in that order, *once* for the life of the socket, not once per send or receive.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do the server like you have in the first example, if you close the stream you can't reopen it like you would want to in the second example.

The problem is going to be wherever you are closing your streams. For whatever reason, it is closed before the server reads the object.

Don't forget you have a `while()` loop in the server while I don't see one for the client in the code you posted. Is it possible you are going through once successfully, and then the server tries to do it again and the client disconnects?